# Changing subscription expire days

Tags: sql-server

When I go to publication properties and General Tab in that. I see an option

```
Subscription expire and may be dropped if not synchronized in the following number of days. Replication meta data is kept for this amount of time.
```

Here some day is set, i.e. 7.

Now I am trying to change this figure to something else, i.e. 20. So If I make this change will the existing subscription reinitialize?

Answer (score 1):

No the subscription will not reinitialize when you make this change.  This setting simply tells the distributor how far behind the subscription can get before the subscription will be automatically expired.